# Can a time series model be improved when the residuals are white noise?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

For a weekly time series, I have been trying some very basic models to get an understanding of time series analysis. The models I tried so far: naive, seasonal naive, an overall mean model, and a simple exponential smoothing (SES) model.

My objective is getting a reasonably accurate forecast. In the end I have to model 2000+ time series, so I would not have time to check every ACF plot, residuals, etc.

The naive and the SES model seem to both do a reasonable job, in the sense that the residuals are white noise. **Edit:** As pointed out in the comments by @BryanKrause, this means that the model cannot be improved.

Three (related) questions to this:

1. How to differentiate between the complexer model (SES) vs the simpler
   model (naive) when in both cases the residuals are white noise? The RMSE is very similar.
2. If I use the Ljung-Box test to check if the residuals are white noise, could it then still be that my series is non-stationary? (aside from sampling error)

I am using the fpp2 package in R and my code is really basic (see below). I am sorry for not providing sample data.

```
y <- ts(data$weekly_sales, start = c(min(data$Year)), frequency = 52)
#weekly_sales = the weekly sales data to be modelled

train <- subset(y, end = length(y)-13)

fit1 <- naive(train, h = 13)
fit2 <- snaive(train, h=13)
fit3 <- meanf(train, h =13)
fit4 <- ses(train, h = 13)

checkresiduals(fit1)
checkresiduals(fit2)
checkresiduals(fit3)
checkresiduals(fit4)

accuracy(fit1, y)
accuracy(fit2, y)
accuracy(fit3, y)
accuracy(fit4, y)
```

Comment: Do you really mean to ask "if the residuals are Gaussian"? If the residuals are indeed actually white noise, then of course the model cannot be improved, any further "fitting" would be fitting noise and therefore overfitting.

Comment: I'm also confused by the term "white noise". The goodness of fit criteria is usually that the residuals are independent.

Comment: @BryanKrause now that you put it like that, my question is indeed a bit stupid. Although I meant exactly what I said, it is as you say. I'll adapt my question to the ones that are only relevant. As for the Gaussian: no I did not mean that. If they're 'perfectly' Gaussian, it means we can interpret the prediction intervals safely, right? If they are not, then the intervals are too wide or small, roughly speaking ofcourse.

Comment: @Amonet You will of course never have 'perfectly' Gaussian residuals (even if you generate random numbers from a normal distribution and fit y ~ epsilon, epsilon won't be perfectly normal), but yes, technically the intervals for your model are most accurate when the residuals are closest to Gaussian. When I'm curious about how much I can rely on a given prediction interval I sometimes like to take a simulation approach to see just how much (or how little) it matters - you'll find that safety comes far before perfection. Heteroskedasticity is typically more problematic when it exists.